# Get data from Node REST API and populate other controls

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest

After login in `React` Web app, I am going to show profile detail to user and I am fetching profile detail from NODE REST API. I am not sure how to do that. I think the problem is in the render section, because if I don't use the render section then it is showing me some data.

```
export class AccountDetails extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     userDetail:null
 }
this.callAPI()

}


async callAPI() {

  await fetch("http://localhost:5000/customers?email="+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('email'))
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(res=>this.setState({userDetail:res}));

  console.log(this.state.userDetail);
  }
```

this is my render section

```
<tr>
   <td className="text-left">First Name : </td>
   <td className="text-left">{this.userDetail.firstName}</td>
</tr>
```

I am getting null in `console.log`

If I don't use `{this.userDetail.firstName}` then I am getting

```
 0:
    email: "manu@gmail.com"
    firstName: "Manpreet"
    lastName: "Narang"
    occupants: 2
    phone: 12345
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using classes you need to make your fetch in `componentDidMount` like so:

```
constructor (props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
      userDetail: null,
      isLoaded: false // Notice this new property and check the render method below
   }
}

componentDidMount() {
   fetch("http://localhost:5000/customers?email="+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('email'))
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => this.setState({ userDetail: res, isLoaded: true }));
}
```

Only then will the `setState` work and rerender your component.

Then, in your `render` method:

```
render() {
   if(!isLoaded) return <p>Loading...</p>

   return (
      <tr>
        <td className="text-left">First Name : </td>
        <td className="text-left">{this.userDetail.firstName}</td>
      </tr>
   )
}
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: I am still not getting anything in console for userDetail

Comment: It worked just added this.state.userDetail.firstName . Thanks